# c++ insert vector in other vector from specific position

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

My target is to insert `vector` in another `vector` from specific position with c++. 
Example:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6};
int position = 1;
```

Output: 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3.

Comment: Have you *looked* at the readily available documentation of the `std::vector` class? Because the information is *right there*....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy:

```
vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6};
int position = 1;
a.insert(a.begin()+position,b.begin(),b.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do it by [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function.

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b = {4, 5, 6};
auto it = a.begin();
int position = 1;
a.insert(it+position, b.begin(), b.end());
```